# webserver with lwip (Cortex M3, Stellaris LM3S6965 Evaluation Board)

Tags: c, cortex-m, lwip

I'm trying to make simple webserver so if I search on my browser and enter the ip of my device I see a webpage. I found [this](http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Sample_Web_Server) wiki page

I have followed the steps, but I have an error while building.

I have includes the linked folder `"C:\stellarisware\third_party\lwip-1.3.2\apps\httpserver_raw"` to get the httpd.c, etc files

I added `httpd_init()` but while building I get this error.

```
   [cc] C:\stellarisware\third_party\lwip-1.3.2\apps\httpserver_raw\fsdata.c:328:26: error: array type has incomplete element type
   [cc] C:\stellarisware\third_party\lwip-1.3.2\apps\httpserver_raw\fsdata.c:330:26: error: array type has incomplete element type
   [cc] C:\stellarisware\third_party\lwip-1.3.2\apps\httpserver_raw\fsdata.c:332:26: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

If I look at that files, this is in it:

```
const struct fsdata_file file_img_sics_gif[] = {{NULL, data_img_sics_gif, data_img_sics_gif + 14, sizeof(data_img_sics_gif) - 14}};

const struct fsdata_file file_404_html[] = {{file_img_sics_gif, data_404_html, data_404_html + 10, sizeof(data_404_html) - 10}};

const struct fsdata_file file_index_html[] = {{file_404_html, data_index_html, data_index_html + 12, sizeof(data_index_html) - 12}};
```

This is how my dir look like:

[image]

Here are the source files from the webserver: [download](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17865437/httpserver_raw.rar)

And here is my main.c, on line 270 I called the httpd_init(); [Download](http://codepaste.net/yx72oh)

Comment: You need to show more code, and perhaps also the makefile or however you're building this. It's borderline too large/specific to be answerable here, though.

Comment: I have edited it, but also I think that the makefile generates the file to display. But where can I change so it displays a html page what I enter.

Comment: The compiler is telling you it doesn't know what the `struct`s look like since their definition is not visible at the point in the code where your arrays are. Probably you need to `#include` more things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude `fsdata.c` from build: Right Click on the file -> Resource Configurations -> Exclude from Build -> Select All.

This file is auto-generated, and there is an `#include "fsdata.c"` statement in `fs.c` IIRC. The `.c` extension is a bit misleading in this case - it is a `C` source file but cannot be compiled alone, only as part of another file which has all the definitions and `#include` lines.